# Multiple event actioned on jquery dummy form (hide/show)

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a watered down version of my situation. Simply put, I get multiple event activated every time I hide/show my div.

I'm adding a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ja09srcm/16/) for my code but here's what goes wrong:

1. You click the show button and you get a dummy hiden form.
2. You click Departed and you'll note the console shows: departed (so far so good. `One click One message`).
3. You click hide - the form goes dark
4. You click show again and click Departed button again --> **PROBLEM**: the console shows twice 'departed' (hide again and show again, you'll get it 3 times and so forth). I expect it to show only ONCE (one click one console event).

I suspect the hide (maybe?) is not the right function. I tried detach/remove but then I can't see the form. I also added 'return false' but the problem still there.

[image]

```
class XBox
{
  show()
  {
    $('.tpbox').show();
  }

hide()
{
    $('.tpbox').hide();     
    return false;
}

setButtons()
{ 

    $( "#div-tpbox-departed" ).on( "click", function() {
      console.log("departed");
      return false;
    });
    
    
    $( "#div-tpbox-hide" ).on( "click", function() {

        $('.tpbox').hide();       
        return false;
    });
}
}


let xbox = new XBox()

function activate()
{
     xbox.show();
     xbox.setButtons();
}
```

and the HTML

```
<button class="btn" onclick='activate()'>show</i></button>
```

```
       <table width="100%">

                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-close fa-2x" style="color:red" onclick="xbox.hide();">&nbsp</i></a>
       
       
                 <div id='div-tpbox-departed' class="btn btn-primary  ">Departed</div>
        <div id='div-tpbox-hide' class="btn btn-primary  ">hide</div>

    <BR>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you click `show` you're calling `xbox.setButtons();` which is adding new eventlisteners. This means if you just click `show` a bunch of times you're adding more event listeners to the `Departed` button.

The best way to fix this is to only set the event listeners once:

```
 function activate()
 {
   xbox.show();
 }
 
 // init
xbox.setButtons(); // remove this from the activate function and call it once.
```

```js
class XBox {
  show() {
    $(".tpbox").show();
  }

  hide() {
    $("#div-tpbox-departed").off("click");
    $(".tpbox").hide();
    return false;
  }

  setButtons() {
    $("#div-tpbox-departed").on("click", function() {
      console.log("departed");
      return false;
    });

    $("#div-tpbox-hide").on("click", function() {
      $(".tpbox").hide();
      return false;
    });
  }
}

let xbox = new XBox();

function activate() {
  xbox.show();
}
xbox.setButtons();
```

```css
#tpbox-dynamic {
  width: 250px;
  line-height: 25px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  left: 55px;
  top: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 500 !important;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

#tpbox-dynamic.minimize {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 5px;
}

#tpbox-dynamic h1 {
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 5px;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

#tpbox-dynamic.minimize h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#tpbox-dynamic p {
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

#tpbox-dynamic.minimize p {
  font-size: 0px;
}

#tpbox-dynamic small {
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 0;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

#tpbox-dynamic.minimize small {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn" onclick='activate()'>show</i></button>

<div class="tpbox" style="display:none">
  <div id="tpbox-dynamic">

    <table width="100%">

      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-close fa-2x" style="color:red" onclick="xbox.hide();">&nbsp</i></a>


      <div id='div-tpbox-departed' class="btn btn-primary  ">Departed</div>
      <div id='div-tpbox-hide' class="btn btn-primary  ">hide</div>

      <BR>
  </div>
</div>
```